# Failed to Send Email using SMTP in Android?

Tags: java, android, smtp

I am newbie in Android and I have followed this tutorial 
[SMTP link](http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-sdk-smtp-email-tutorial/)
[another SMTP tutorial](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android)

But unfortunately I failed to send emails from emulator/device S3,every time I try I am getting "CATCH" block message. 
This is class that extends from Activity

```
ImageView submitBtn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.askscreen_submit_btn);
        submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
// CALL GetText method to make post method call
                 m = new Mail("abc@gmail.com","password"); 
                sendEmail(v);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                    content.setText(" url exeption! ");
                }   
            }
        });
    }
    public void sendEmail(View view){
        String[] toArr = {"abc@gmail.com"}; // This is an array, you can add more emails, just separate them with a coma
        m.setTo(toArr); // load array to setTo function
        m.setFrom("abc@gmail.com"); // who is sending the email 
        m.setSubject("subject"); 
        m.setBody("your message goes here"); 

        try { 
            //m.addAttachment("/sdcard/myPicture.jpg");  // path to file you want to attach
            if(m.send()) { 
                // success
                Toast.makeText(AskfatwaActivity.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } else { 
                // failure
                Toast.makeText(AskfatwaActivity.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } 
        } catch(Exception e) { 
            // some other problem
            Toast.makeText(AskfatwaActivity.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } 

    }
```

Can someone please help me what is the reason?

Comment: your using an e-mail api for this ?

Comment: i have also followed this tutorial http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android

Comment: i have followed the above mentioned tutorial can some one please help me

Comment: i have downloaded three jar files activation.jar , mail.jar , another one from this site https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list

Comment: yes @fadytaher i am using Java Mail Api

Comment: i have also tried for port 465 and 587 but none of themm worked

Answer (score 0):

I once implemented this code , it's pretty low level but it did the job , to be honest never used an api so... all help I can actually offer , also note the base64 code thing , username and password must be base64 encoded , so you might want to some library that does it for you

```
  import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.net.Socket;

import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Email {




         public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {


        Socket so = new Socket("smtp.mail.yahoo.com",25);    




BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(so.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter outputStream   = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(so.getOutputStream()),true);


String enemail   =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your e-mail in BASEA64 code");
String password  =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your password in BASEA64 code");
String from      =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "From");
String to        =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "To");
String subject   =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Subject");
String msg       =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Message");

outputStream.println("HELO ");      
System.out.println(inputStream.readLine());



outputStream.println("AUTH LOGIN");     
System.out.println(inputStream.readLine());




outputStream.println(enemail);      
System.out.println(inputStream.readLine());



outputStream.println(password);     
System.out.println(inputStream.readLine());


outputStream.println("VRFY");       
System.out.println(inputStream.readLine());

outputStream.println("MAIL FROM:<"+from+">");       
System.out.println(inputStream.readLine());


outputStream.println("RCPT TO:<"+to+">");       
System.out.println(inputStream.readLine());

outputStream.println("DATA");       
System.out.println(inputStream.readLine());


outputStream.println("Subject:"+subject);
outputStream.println("FROM :<"+from+">");
outputStream.println("TO :<"+to+">");
outputStream.println(msg);
outputStream.println("");       
outputStream.println(".");      
so.close();




         }
         }
```

Comment: how can i add email and pswd using base64

Comment: I would say for start use any online converters and you can download the library from   http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi

Comment: the above mentioned code is fine but not recommended becuase i have to use the code for attachment as well can u please see my code and do some changes in it